# Tensorflow with one label and one feature

Tags: python, tensorflow

Team,

I am new to tensor flow and am trying to build a program based on what I have learned of reading on the web. I am basically using data that I already have to learn and test the model. There are only two columns in my data, one is the feature and one is a label. However I am still struggling to get the algorithm to run. The error am getting is as below.

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (40,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'

I understand that am doing something wrong where the size of my tensors is not matching, but am a bit lost on where to go from here. Any guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [numpy.reshape()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to get the desired shape or use  [Two-Dimensional Slicing](https://machinelearningmastery.com/index-slice-reshape-numpy-arrays-machine-learning-python/).

I can't tell what to do precisely if you don't provide some code example of what you are trying.